# Adding a custom field from OppLineItem to a custom report type

Tags: custom-field, opportunity-lineitem, custom-report-type

I have a custom field on the OpportunityLineItem and want to show it in a custom report.

Current setup:

1. Custom Report Type: Invoices with Asset
2. OpportunityLineItem- child of Opportunity
3. Invoice - child of Opportunity

So, in theory, I should be able to add the custom field in the custom report type, following the path:

```
Invoice Fields(Lookup) > Opportunity > OpportunityLineItem > Custom field.
```

But after the Opportunity > I don't have the OpportunityLineItem option.

What am I missing here and what relationship should I add in order to get the Custom Field from the OpportunityLineItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opportunity does not have a Lookup relationship to Opportunity Line Item. Opportunity Line Item is a child of Opportunity. You cannot descend a master-to-detail object hierarchy using the Add Fields Via Lookup option in a custom report type.

You cannot add this field to your custom report type as described. You would need to consider using a Joined Report or using a Roll-Up Summary Field to surface the information on the Opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @DavidReed. I will use a Joined Report as the custom field is a text field I need to show on a report.